# How to parse a JSON result of an array of object and print in excel?

Tags: python, json, excel

This is a multi-part question. I am looking to make a request and print the result in excel, with the headers at the top all across and the content data in the row below. When I run the following code, I only get the headers printed vertically and no data is shown. So my questions are: 1. How do I get the data to come in? and 2. How can I transform the output so the headers are horizontal in the excel sheet (along with the data to come underneath)?

```
import requests
import json
import pandas
import xlwt

r = requests.get("https://testapp.deribit.com/api/v2/public/get_trade_volumes?")

db=[]

resp = json.loads(r.text)
for data in resp['result'][0]:
    db.append(data)
for data in resp['result'][1]:
    db.append(data)

df1 = pandas.DataFrame(db)
df1.to_excel('C:/Test/daily_volume.xls')
```

Comment: I recommend the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Why are you writing to an XLS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for data in resp` doesn't work quite like you think it does.

```py
In [26]: db=[] 
    ...:  
    ...: resp = response 
    ...: for data in resp['result'][0]: 
    ...:     db.append(data) 
    ...: for data in resp['result'][1]: 
    ...:     db.append(data) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [27]: response                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[27]: 
{'jsonrpc': '2.0',
 'result': [{'puts_volume': 1246.1,
   'futures_volume': 1807294.0335,
   'currency_pair': 'btc_usd',
   'calls_volume': 767.4},
  {'puts_volume': 64.0,
   'futures_volume': 130999.2335,
   'currency_pair': 'eth_usd',
   'calls_volume': 79.0}],
 'usIn': 1575569314303219,
 'usOut': 1575569314304869,
 'usDiff': 1650,
 'testnet': True}

In [28]: db                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[28]: 
['puts_volume',
 'futures_volume',
 'currency_pair',
 'calls_volume',
 'puts_volume',
 'futures_volume',
 'currency_pair',
 'calls_volume']
```

You don't have to loop through it that way anyway. With the given JSON structure, you can pass that directly into pandas and get what you're after.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://testapp.deribit.com/api/v2/public/get_trade_volumes?").json()
pd.DataFrame(response["result"]).to_excel("daily_volume.xls")
```

Produces

[image]